# Why are there always these many files to commit in Xcode? (Even right after I've just committed them.)

Tags: xcode, git, github

Even after I've committed and pushed local changes to my github account, these 112 files still appear in the list and the button still says "Commit 112" files.

What's happening here?

[image: files from Pods folder in Xcode show a modified status]

Comment: Maybe your Pods folder is listed in some `.gitignore`? Try closing-reopening Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! Nothing was working, so I ended up completely uninstalling and reinstalling all the pods using these instructions: https://medium.com/@satishios25/uninstalling-podfile-form-the-xcode-project-7e96874ae7f4

It seems to have worked.

Comment: Instead of linking to a different website, you could say you simply did: `pod deintegrate & pod install`